# How to do cosine similarity between two dataFrame efficiently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cosine-similarity

I have one DataFrame (`d1`) with `(index, features)` and a second one (`d2`) with the same columns.

`features` is a `Seq[Double]`, and `index` is a `String`.

`d1` would be about a million rows, and `d2` could be between 40 to 10,000.

I would like to get at the end a DataFrame with `(index, CosineSimilarities)` `CosineSimilarities` will be: for each `d1` rows, a `Seq[Double]` equal to the cosine similarity between this row and each row of `d2`. So `CosineSimilarities` length should be equal to `d2` number of rows.

My first approach was to use `DenseMatrix` and `IndexedRowMatrix` and `d1.multiply(d2.transpose)`. But it is really hard to map the results back to the `index` and when `d2` get large, the task break.

My second approach was do:

```
d1
  .cartesian(d2)
  .repartition(n)
  .map { case ((d1index, d1features), (_, d2features)) =>
    (d1index, myCosineSimilarityMethod(d1features, d2features))
  }
```

But this is painfully slow.

My third approach is the `Broadcast` `d2` and do row by row, that way:

```
d1
  .mapValues { d1features =>
      d2broadcasted
        .value
        .map { case (_, d2features) =>
          myCosineSimilarityMethod(d1features, d2features)
        }
        .toSeq
    )
  }
```

And it works, it is more scalable and faster than approach2 but not as fast as approach1.

Is there an other, better way ?

**Edit:**

I had an idea to calculate the center of `d2` and then calculate the distance between each `d1` to this center. Would that work ? Is there a way to get the centroid of a dataframe ?

Comment: How many columns do you expect? Do you make any assumptions about data distribution?

Comment: No, it will be a utility method so that can change.